# "This field is required" after submitting form in a filled field using django and AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, frontend

I have been trying to add ajax to my django project these past days and I am finding problems with the form submission and data displaying. When I submit a POST form with just one field (with required =True) it does not recognize the form as a valid form (do not pass the .is_valid if) and the form error says "This field is required":

forms.py

```
enter code here

from django import forms
import datetime

class FriendForm(forms.Form):
      
    name = forms.CharField( required=True,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special', 'id':'id_name', 'name':'name'}))
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers
from .forms import FriendForm, form_busqueda_address
from .models import Friend
import json
import requests
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

def indexView (request):
    form = FriendForm ()
    friends = Friend.objects.all ()
    return render (request, "index.html", {"form": form, "friends": friends})



def searchFriend(request):
    form = FriendForm ()
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = FriendForm (request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form = FriendForm (request.POST)
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            query = Friend.objects.filter(nick_name=name)
            responseData = serializers.serialize('json', list(query))
            return JsonResponse(responseData, safe=False)

        else:

            print(form.errors)
            query = {
                        'errors': form.errors,
                    }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(query), content_type="application/json")
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
 
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
});


var getData;


        $("#form1").submit(function(e) {// catch the form's submit event
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $("#id_name").val();
        
        var $content = $('#display');
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                type: 'post',
                data: $(search).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "search/ajax/friend/",
                success: function(query) { // on success..
                   

                    console.log(query)
             
                
                }
            });
            
        });

        $("#form-ajax").submit(function(e) { // catch the form's submit eve
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('ok')
                });
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <form method="post" id="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <button type="submit"  value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
```

**EDIT 1**:

I have modified main.js in order to change where .serialize() was pointing and alse have deleted the csrf token function. The current main.js is:

```
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {// catch the form's submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $("#id_name").val();
    
    var $content = $('#display');
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'search' :  $(this).serialize(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "search/ajax/friend/",
            success: function(query) { // on success..
               

                console.log(query)
         
            
            }
        });
        
    });
```

If we go to browser we can se the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpepy.png)

It seems like the form is actually getting the field info, but for whatever reason my view take it as empty.

Comment: What does `print(request.POST)` show is actually being returned?

Comment: An empty querydict is returned:  "<QueryDict: {}>" It is like it is ignoring the input in the input field. Any idea? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the browser console and step through you Javascript code to see if it is working like you think it is.

Comment: It seems the `.serialize` is incorrect. See here [Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). It should be something like: `$( this ).serialize()`. If you want to work on a single element use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your help again. I have tried serialize(), but my form stills being evaluated as empty even when I filled it

Comment: 1) Why do the JS submit anyway? Just use the Submit button to POST the form to the URL. 2) The form.serialize() is now buried in the in the 'search' key. You have not changed your view code to accommodate.